# Function to return modified matrix in R

Tags: r, function, matrix, dataframe, xts

The following code adds vector `XTS1$XTSSum2` to xts object `XTS1`:

```
library(xts)
XTS1 <- structure(c(12, 7, 7, 22, 24, 30, 26, 23, 27, 30), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"), .CLASS = structure("double", class = "CLASS"), formattable = structure(list(formatter = "formatC", format = structure(list(format = "f", digits = 2), .Names = c("format", "digits")), preproc = "percent_preproc", postproc = "percent_postproc"), .Names = c("formatter", "format", "preproc", "postproc")), index = structure(c(1413981900, 1413982800, 1413983700, 1413984600, 1413985500, 1413986400, 1413987300, 1413988200, 1413989100, 1413990000), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(10L, 1L))
colnames(XTS1) <- "XTS1"
XTS1$XTSSum2 <- XTS1$XTS1 + lag(XTS1$XTS1,1)
```

The following function performs the same operation.

```
addfunction <- function(x){
  x$XTSSum2 <- x$XTS1 + lag(x$XTS1,1)
}
addfunction(XTS1)
```

But the vector `XTS1$XTSSum2` is not stored. 
How can I get `addfunction` to store the vector so that after running `addfunction(XTS1)`, `XTS1` will look like this:

```
                     XTS1 XTSSum2
2014-10-22 08:45:00   12      NA
2014-10-22 09:00:00    7      19
2014-10-22 09:15:00    7      14
2014-10-22 09:30:00   22      29
2014-10-22 09:45:00   24      46
2014-10-22 10:00:00   30      54
2014-10-22 10:15:00   26      56
2014-10-22 10:30:00   23      49
2014-10-22 10:45:00   27      50
2014-10-22 11:00:00   30      57
```

The reproducible example uses an xts object, presume the same solution would apply
to xts objects, matrices and data frames.

Comment: Try `<<-` instead of `<-` inside your function. But usually you do not want to do anything like that.

Comment: just `<<-` is not working because `x` will not be found. You need to do `XTS1$XTSSum2 <<- x$XTS1 + lag(x$XTS1,1)` inside your function. But clearly you do not want to do that.

Comment: Thanks. The @EricWatt answer worked without using `<<`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment is happening within the function's environment, not the global one. You need to return the result in the function, and assign it with the function call. Try this:

```
addfunction <- function(x){
  x$XTSSum2 <- x$XTS1 + lag(x$XTS1,1)
  x
}
XTS1 <- addfunction(XTS1)
```

Comment: from the above example, if only want  XTS1 and XTSum2 in the above example, how can I get it in the function? how can I return the output in the form of matrix?